# Clustering and plotting Using UMAP

Tags: plot, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to study the shape of some datasets using UMAP. I have all my data in three matrices A_1,A_2,A_3, which contain vectors of the same dimension.

I would like to transform them together Using UMAP, and plot them in a way that the colours of the plotting changes with respect of the matrix it belongs to. In other words, I want to be able to distinguish the three classes.

```
    fit = umap.UMAP()
    %time u = fit.fit_transform(A)

    plt.scatter(u[:,0], u[:,1])
```

gives me the representation with respect of A. I have tried, and it worked, to concatenate the vectors in a unique matrix. The only problem is that, arrived at that point, I have no idea how to distinguish the points in the plot. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Distinguish them by their indexes.

I.e., fincat them, project, un-concat by their indexes.

Just as you'd do with a label column.